# Find documents using Mongoose where parent and child both match query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, querying

I have the following 2 Mongoose schemas for a MongoDB:

```
// Parent Schema
var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    status: { type: String, required: true }
    child: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child', required: true },
    ...
}

//Child schema
var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    status: { type: String, required: true }
    ...
}
```

I want to find all parent documents where status = published and where the child document  status = published also. None of the following give the desired results:

```
//This returns no documents
Parent.find({ 'status': 'published' })
    .where({ 'child.status': 'published' })
    .populate('child')
    .exec(function (err, results) {

//This returns no documents
Parent.find({ 'status': 'published' })
    .populate('child')
    .where({ 'child.status': 'published' })
    .exec(function (err, results) {

//This filters by parent status but not child status
Parent.find({ status: 'published' })
    .populate({
        path: 'child',
        match: { 'child.status': 'published' }
    })
    .exec(function (err, results) {

//This returns no documents 
Parent.find(
    {status: 'published', 'child.status': 'published'},
    {child:{$elemMatch:{status: 'published'}}})
    .exec(function (err, results) {
```

Is this the right approach or is there a different technique that should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB it is not possible to query more than one collections in a single query. If `Child` was embedded as a subdocument in `Parent` then you could do a query on `child.status` but since it is a separate collection which is referenced in `Parent` you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can with Waterline, it is much more ORM like.